# Фоторедактор на Android

Tags: android

В маркете есть множество приложений типа https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fotoable.fotobeauty, где можно наложить на фотографию эффекты, подправить фото, обрезать и т.д. Подскажите пожалуйста. Есть ли каике-нибудь библиотеки для этого или все эффекты в таких приложениях в коде прописаны? Понятное дело что это не простое приложение и сев за один вечер не напишешь, но мне интересно как эффекты в таких приложениях реализованы

Comment: Библиотеки есть конечно, выбирайте: [Search·android image filters·GitHub](https://github.com/search?p=2&q=android+image+filters&type=Repositories&utf8=%E2%9C%93).

Comment: Спасибо, буду смотреть